# Run Map Reduce on non-default versions?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I have a couple of questions about the App Engine Map Reduce API. First of all there's a mapreduce package in the SDK, and there's a separate mapreduce bundle here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads

Which one should I be using? Should I be using the bundle, or is the documentation out of date and I should actually use the SDK version?

Second I'd like to be able to run mapreduce's on a non-default version to make sure that the requests from the mapreduce don't interfere with user requests.

What's the best way to do this? Can I start the pipeline with a task queue, and set the target version of that queue to be my non-default version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recommend using the open source version of Map Reduce for GAE at http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/

The stale bundle link in the docs is a bug. That'll get cleaned up soon.

A few of our SDKs have bits of MapReduce (for historic reasons), but the open source version is the way to go for now.

As for using a separate version, this is kind of "it depends". If you're thinking of interference in terms of competition for the processor, that's not likely to be a noticeable issue. Depending on queue processing rates you've set up, more instances of your app will be spun up to handle mapping tasks as needed. I'd try some experiments first. Make sure you have a problem before you invest time and effort solving it.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. As far as my second question goes, any recommendations? Is separating mapreduce requests from user requests on a separate version even a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

mapreduce can be start on a not default version. And after it starts, it will continue run on that version automatically.

In my case I just deploy the code on a non default version and trigger the mapreduce with version_id.app_id.appspot.com/path_to_start_a_job.

cron job can also trigger the mapreduce on non default version without problem.