# Mapreduce job randomly fails with 'BadValueError: name must be under 500'

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, mapreduce

I am running a map reduce job which maps roughly 100k records.

The map step fails after several thousand records (different place every time) with the following error in the app engine logs   *BadValueError: name must be under 500*

> Pipeline job id: baada59c857d11e28527e1efd5a519d7
>
> Output Blob file name: content_contributors_report_1362478582.csv

log dump

```
 Final result for job '1581739058957C0CA88F5' is 'success' E2013-03-05
 12:25:21.637 name must be under 500 bytes. Traceback (most recent call
 last):   File
 "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
 line 1535, in __call__
     rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
 line 1529, in __call__
     rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
 line 1278, in default_dispatcher
     return route.handler_adapter(request, response)   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
 line 1102, in __call__
     return handler.dispatch()   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
 line 572, in dispatch
     return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py",
 line 570, in dispatch
     return method(*args, **kwargs)   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myap/a-276.365486148015822746/mapreduce/base_handler.py",
 line 68, in post
     self.handle()   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/a-276.365486148015822746/mapreduce/handlers.py",
 line 437, in handle
     spec, state, self.base_path())   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/a-276.365486148015822746/mapreduce/handlers.py",
 line 517, in _finalize_job
     mapreduce_spec.mapper.output_writer_class().finalize_job(mapreduce_state)
 File
 "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/a-276.365486148015822746/mapreduce/output_writers.py",
 line 454, in finalize_job
     files.blobstore.get_blob_key(filename)))   File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/a-276.365486148015822746/mapreduce/lib/files/blobstore.py",
 line 112, in get_blob_key
     _BLOB_FILE_INDEX_KIND, ticket, namespace='')])[0]   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py",
 line 504, in from_path
     ValidateString(id_or_name, 'name')   File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py",
 line 176, in ValidateString
     raise exception('%s must be under %d bytes.' % (name, max_len)) BadValueError: name must be under 500 bytes.
```

Comment: which version of mapreduce you are using?

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178869/overcome-appengine-500-byte-string-limit-in-python-consider-text

Comment: thanks @lucemia, turns out i was using the wrong version, a while back i had to download a seprate mapreduce library and add it to my project codebase, I now reverted to the bundled with the SDK and this seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The different version of mapreduce may cause this problem.
based on [Run Map Reduce on non-default versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148527/run-map-reduce-on-non-default-versions/15170392)
It recommended to use https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/

> The stale bundle link in the docs is a bug. That'll get cleaned up
>   soon.
>
> A few of our SDKs have bits of MapReduce (for historic reasons), but
>   the open source version is the way to go for now.

Comment: We ended up reverting to the version in the SDK